# How can I prevent multiple runs of Action_open_Document_tree when button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

**Problem**:I am currently working in Android Project in that I Declared Action_open_Document_tree in button.set on click listener but whenever I click button the Action_open_Document_tree run again and again.

I tried Like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(v -> { Intent intent = new      Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
         intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, (Parcelable[]) null);
         startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Expectation : My expectation is when I click the button Action_open_Document_tree ask one time only ,If I click again that button Action_open_Document_tree should not work.

Comment: Why are you using initial uri if you dont use it? Which effect does it have?

Comment: `Action_open_Document_tree` Please write it down as it should be written.

Comment: `If I click again that button Action_open_Document_tree should not work.` Oh... Well simply disable the button. Or make it invisible.

Comment: Only disable button in onActivityResult when not cancelled.

Comment: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. this my error while using Action_open_Document_tree

Comment: You did not read my second comment? And post the errors in your post. Not afterwards in a comment. Your post is about something different. Dont confuse us.